# Why is getResource or getResourceAsStream method placed in Class.java?

Tags: java, jvm

The way I see it, these methods are used to fetch a resource and return the respective object. So why are they placed in Class.java? They're not providing any information or metadata about the class then why put it in 'class' class and not in IO package?

Answer (score 3):

<sup>I'll only mention `getResource` here, but everything equally applies to `getResourceAsStream`.</sup>

Those methods are about loading resources that are bundled with your classes, so they are *somewhat* related to what `Class` does. But there is indeed a place where they would fit better. And that is `ClassLoader`.

And in fact, there is [a `ClassLoader.getResource` method](http://It%27s%20correct%20that%20there%27s%20a%20better%20place%20for%20methods%20like%20that,%20and%20that%27s) that looks awfully similar to [the `Class` version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) of the same name.

In fact the major difference between those two methods is that the `Class` version will prepend the modified package name to the front of the requested resource name, if it doesn't start with `/`.

That means that `mypackage.MyClass.class.getResource("foo")` is (almost, but not quite) equivalent to `mypackage.MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("mypackage/foo")`. This makes the `Class` version very useful to load resources that are tightly related to a given class (one could say "are in the same package", except that's not quite technically true).

Comment: The module system introduced in Java 9 has a different opinion. If `mypackage` is an actual package of a module, the resource `mypackage/foo` is considered to be in that package and the caller must be in the same module or the package must have been opened to the caller, to be able to access the resource. So class `mypackage.MyClass` and resource `mypackage/foo` are in the same package, even technically.

Comment: @Holger: I hadn't realized that resources are now officially in a package, thanks for the info. I've not used these APIs directly when related to modules, so I can't really comment on how exactly that works.